Vertical histogram
What is the nicest way to visualize change of variables as below density as below? IE, value 2 appears 3 times, so it gets a higher bin-count than other values, but the histogram is vertical to align with the values in the leftmost plot.

Here's the visualization of the leftmost plot
ListPlot[{4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1}, Filling -> Axis]


Histogram[{4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1}, BarOrigin -> Left]



Simple & nice !

I don't fully understand what is your question. If the rightmost plot is what you want, then how about this?
data = {4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1};
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Orange}], White, 
  Rectangle[{0, #[[1]] - 1}, #[[{2, 1}]]] & /@ Tally[data]}, 
 Axes -> True]


